# PHP For Loop dynamic from database

Tags: php

I'm generating my check boxes from this code. But, I'm having difficulty with making it generate by 5 outputs then once the 5th output is displayed it should skip to the next line.
Would appreciate any help.

```
<?php 
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value='.$row['type_id'].'>'
            .'<label>'.$row['type_name']. '</label>'.'<br>'.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Its already showing every next result in a new line

Comment: so put a counter in your while loop and do continue when it is  == 5

Comment: Kinda hacky but if you want a 1 liner: `if (@++$i == 5) continue;`

Comment: Yes. But, Instead of **Checkbox <br>** I would really like a **Checkbox Checkbox Checkbox Checkbox Checkbox <br>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value='.$row['type_id'].'><label>'.$row['type_name']. '</label>';
if($i%5==0)
{
   echo "<br>";
}
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
                $i=0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                if($i%5 == 0){
                 //skip to next line
                 //continue??
                 }
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value='.$row['type_id'].'>'.'
                <label>'.$row['type_name']. '</label>'.'<br>'.'<br>';                   
                $i++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is how to skip every 5th entry and to put a linebreak instead?

Have a try like this:

```
<?php 
    $i=0;
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        if (++$i % 5)
            echo sprintf ( '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="%s">'
                          .'<label>%s</label>'."\n", 
                           htmlentities($row['type_id']), 
                           htmlentities($row['type_name']) );
        else
            echo "<br>\n";
    }
?>
```

In addition to iterating over all entries in the result just use a counter you increment with every iteration. Then, inside the iteration, only output the current entry if the counter modulo 5 is not zero. So if it is not a clean multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<?php 
    $i =1;
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($i == 5){
      echo "<br>";
      $i = 1;
    }
    else
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" value='.$row['type_id'].'>'
            .'<label>'.$row['type_name']. '</label>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```